# Would like to understand why Social Security Administration (SSA) snafu happened

Tags: united-states, social-security, death

My bank resolved the following problem in less than two days, but I would like to understand why/how the problem happened.

My husband died in mid-January, and several days later his Social Security check was deposited in our checking account.  About 6 weeks later, the SSA took back the deposited check, which is Standard Operating Procedure when a check is issued after death.

A few days ago the SSA took back the check **again.**  I went to the bank and they said they would fix it, and they did.  Everything is OK.

But why did this happen?  Is this, if not a common error, at least not unheard of?

The only connection I can think of is that two or three weeks ago, I retitled the checking account by removing my husband's name, because his SS# was the reporting number.  Coincidence or cause?

This snafu could be a real hardship for many people, especially if they did not have such an efficient and acomodating bank as I did.

Any experts out there who can explain this snafu?

Comment: Being a (former) computer programmer who worked on this kind of system, I can imagine a complicated set of rules implemented with some bugs.  You renaming the checking account probably initiated one of those corner case bugs.

Comment: Forgive me for being indelicate, keep in mind as you get closer to year end, you still file as MFJ, and that brings a $24K standard deduction, and married/joint tax brackets. This might suggest a Roth conversion, or retirement acct withdrawal this year.

Comment: @Joe Taxpayer Yes, thank you, I know I file as MFJ, but your comment will be useful for others in my position reading this post. As for the standard deduction, it is advantageous for me to itemize.   And I am, unfortunately,  years beyond doing anything with retirement accounts except taking the RMD. But again, thank you for your thoughtfulness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best guess is that the arm (or maybe *tentacle*?) of the SSA that requested the return wasn't yet informed of the success by the other arm that processed the returned money - any incoming money has to go through a processing where it gets assigned to the proper account, and that might just take a while.

Otherwise...things get lost... this is government we are talking about.

Comment: Seven Months?   (March to October).  (Love tentacle.)